# cron_job.sh command not found on AWS ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to get a cron job working, but I get a "command not found" issue when trying to run it.

write_file.py and cron_job.sh are in the same folder in some folder in /home/ubuntu

write_file.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
with open("pythonwrite.txt","a") as f:
    f.write("Hello Cron Jobs at {} \n".format(datetime.now()))
```

cron_job.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH = '/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/XXX/bin'
python3 write_file.py
```

While in a Terminal within this folder, I get this message whenever I try to run various commands:

```
cron_job.sh command not found
```

Attempted commands:

```
***** cron_job.sh
* * * * * cron_job.sh
* * * * * cron_job
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/example_folder/cron_job.sh
```

I have already done this in the example_folder prior and there was no output when I ran this:

```
sudo chmod +x cron_job.sh
```

How to get this example cron job running?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues I see.

1. The error msg writes about `cron_script.sh`, and you are using `cron_job.sh`. Guess everything should `cron_script.sh`?
2. `PATH = '/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/XXX/bin'` is incorrect. It should be `PATH='/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/XXX/bin'`. But I don't see any use of it in the code provided anyway.
3. `* * * * /home/ubuntu/<folder_name>/cron_job.sh` is correct, but its not clear what is `<folder_name>`. Are you files actually in `/home/ubuntu/<folder_name>` or in `/home/ubuntu`? Also, is it `cron_job.sh` or `cron_script.sh` as the error message clearly indicates.

Comment: oh yeah, typo on the title, it should be cron_job.sh. <folder_name> is just a placeholder, I'll name it something in the main post. Thanks for the reply!